# How can I repair stacking doors that are not closing properly and running off the track?

Tags: wood

I live near a dam. My front entrance runs along a canal

## Stacked / Folding Wooden Doors

I have 4 X 6 pane stacking doors at each of my balconies and I am experiencing the following problems.

1. The doors are running off the track
2. Very difficult to get the first pane folded followed with the rest of them. At some point while sliding the doors it comes off the railing.
3. Too much effort required to fold and unfold these doors
4. Key latch is misaligned against the frame slot
5. Water leaking through the edges of the doors

## Sliding Wooden Windows

1. Similar problems as above
2. Water leaking through the gaps within the windows.

Comment: Will need pictures of the issues, sometimes it is a simple fix if all the details can be seen. then again sometimes things aren't so simple fix.

Comment: What climate?  What relevance does your location near a dam have to the sticking doors?

Comment: Could be house settling and things not lining up anymore, could be stuck bearings or worn down bushings depending on the door, could be debris in the track, could be a million things. Take some up-close photos, bonus if you can get a video for us.